# why opencv templete match function not accurate at all

Tags: c++, opencv

I use opencv templete match function to judge one image is in a other image, the templete image is just a part screenshot of original image.i use the demo on official website like that:

```
#include "opencv2/imgcodecs.hpp"
#include "opencv2/highgui.hpp"
#include "opencv2/imgproc.hpp"
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
using namespace cv;
bool use_mask;
Mat img; Mat templ; Mat mask; Mat result;
const char* image_window = "Source Image";
const char* result_window = "Result window";
int match_method;
int max_Trackbar = 5;
void MatchingMethod( int, void* );
int main( int argc, char** argv )
{
  if (argc < 3)
  {
    cout << "Not enough parameters" << endl;
    cout << "Usage:\n./MatchTemplate_Demo <image_name> <template_name> [<mask_name>]" << endl;
    return -1;
  }
  img = imread( argv[1], IMREAD_COLOR );
  templ = imread( argv[2], IMREAD_COLOR );
  if(argc > 3) {
    use_mask = true;
    mask = imread( argv[3], IMREAD_COLOR );
  }
  if(img.empty() || templ.empty() || (use_mask && mask.empty()))
  {
    cout << "Can't read one of the images" << endl;
    return -1;
  }
  namedWindow( image_window, WINDOW_AUTOSIZE );
  namedWindow( result_window, WINDOW_AUTOSIZE );
  const char* trackbar_label = "Method: \n 0: SQDIFF \n 1: SQDIFF NORMED \n 2: TM CCORR \n 3: TM CCORR NORMED \n 4: TM COEFF \n 5: TM COEFF NORMED";
  createTrackbar( trackbar_label, image_window, &match_method, max_Trackbar, MatchingMethod );
  MatchingMethod( 0, 0 );
  waitKey(0);
  return 0;
}
void MatchingMethod( int, void* )
{
  Mat img_display;
  img.copyTo( img_display );
  int result_cols =  img.cols - templ.cols + 1;
  int result_rows = img.rows - templ.rows + 1;
  result.create( result_rows, result_cols, CV_32FC1 );
  bool method_accepts_mask = (TM_SQDIFF == match_method || match_method == TM_CCORR_NORMED);
  if (use_mask && method_accepts_mask)
    { matchTemplate( img, templ, result, match_method, mask); }
  else
    { matchTemplate( img, templ, result, match_method); }
  normalize( result, result, 0, 1, NORM_MINMAX, -1, Mat() );
  double minVal; double maxVal; Point minLoc; Point maxLoc;
  Point matchLoc;
  minMaxLoc( result, &minVal, &maxVal, &minLoc, &maxLoc, Mat() );
  if( match_method  == TM_SQDIFF || match_method == TM_SQDIFF_NORMED )
    { matchLoc = minLoc; }
  else
    { matchLoc = maxLoc; }
  rectangle( img_display, matchLoc, Point( matchLoc.x + templ.cols , matchLoc.y + templ.rows ), Scalar::all(0), 2, 8, 0 );
  rectangle( result, matchLoc, Point( matchLoc.x + templ.cols , matchLoc.y + templ.rows ), Scalar::all(0), 2, 8, 0 );
  imshow( image_window, img_display );
  imshow( result_window, result );
  return;
}
```

but it does`nt work , not accurate at all,and why? i use the opencv 4 ,and i not change any code in demo.

anyone can help me ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried that code once. It is true that it is not accurate and there were many mistaken matches also. If you will find the same thing in the same image, you can take the pixel values of the template then you can search those pixel values on the image. The fitted one will be your template. The way learning pixel values of an image is that:

```
  for(int i = 0; i < img.rows; i++)
{
    for(int j = 0; j < img.cols; j++)
    {
        Vec3b bgr_values = img.at<Vec3b>(i, j);
        //This bgr_values will give you the code of each pixel
    }
}
```

Template matching is similar to one-shot learning which will never work accurately because you are using only one image as reference. If you only look for a specific template you can develop an algorithm according to that object using basic morphological opencv functions. If you need accurate results maybe you need to use some deep learning algorithms. I can advise you YOLO which is easy to use and you can look at [here](https://www.learnopencv.com/training-yolov3-deep-learning-based-custom-object-detector/)

Comment: thanks a lot!,i'm going to see something about deep learning and YOLO you saied,i will write result here if i succeed